# What does object mean in the Document object model (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was learning about *DOM*. The definition says that it is a representation of HTML document in a tree like structure to interact with the document. I I don't understand what *object* or *object model* means in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Object is a general term in programming and not one unique to the DOM.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/object) is a reasonable place to start for an overview on objects.

> Object refers to a data structure containing data and instructions for working with the data. Objects sometimes refer to real-world things, for example a car or map object in a racing game. JavaScript, Java, C++, Python, and Ruby are examples of object-oriented programming languages.

You might want to get to grips with object-oriented programming in general. [MDN has an introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS) using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is `Document Object Model` and not `Document Object Modal`, it is funny.

The `object` means that each element of the document (known as `node`) is represented as an object with its properties.

You can find more information here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

In particular in the section `Applications > JavaScript`.

It says:

"When a web page is loaded, the browser creates a Document Object Model of the page, which is an object oriented representation of an HTML document that acts as an interface between JavaScript and the document itself."

Comment: What does it mean to be a tree like structure in DOM, does it mean representation of objects in the form of tree

Comment: Yes, for example you have the `html` that has two child: the `head` and the `body` and so on.

Comment: Does in tree representation objects and node are same thing. What is difference between node and object.