# What's the meaning of "Model" in Document Object Model ( DOM )?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning web development and came across the concept of DOM. There are many resources which have explained what is DOM and what it does.

But I couldn't find any resource explaining meaning of "Model" in "Document Object Model ( DOM )". What does it mean ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does object mean in the Document object model (DOM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215959/what-does-object-mean-in-the-document-object-model-dom)

Comment: No, it doesn't answer. This question is different.

Comment: People usually interchange DOM with its Model. The model defines what Objects are provided to you by the browser, what properties do they have, the meaning of each property and also the available methods that each Object provides. Everything that you read/hear about DOM actually refers to its Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found couple of good answers as below

1. In programming the term "model" often refers to a data structure.
   For the DOM, it is referring to the structure of the document.
   The document is an object with properties and the structure of it all
   is predetermined by the model.
2. In a general sense, “model” can just be the shape of data. Like in a language like TypeScript, I might define a person as:

   > ```
   > interface Person {
   >   name: string
   >   age: number
   >   address: {
   >     house: number
   >     street: string
   >     city: string
   >     state: string
   >     zip: string
   >   }
   >   phones: string[]
   > }
   > ```

That is just the model for how I represent a “person” in my data.

In a more general sense, the DOM is just a model, an abstract representation of what is on the screen. It (the data and therefore the model) has a certain shape and hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

As the name suggests, it's a model for things
In this case, model of the document
A model is as the plan of city or house, it describes how it look

The model describe and give you the representation of your document